# A polynomial $ f $ in three variables with real coefficients and any line $l$ in $ \mathbb R^3 $

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, multivariable-calculus, polynomials

> Prove that for every polynomial $ f $ in three variables with real coefficients and any line $\ell$ in $ \mathbb R^3 $
> either $ \ell \subset Z_f $ or $ |\ell \cap Z_f|\leq \deg f $, where
> $$ Z_f :=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: f(x,y,z)=0 \}.$$

Here is the case for a polynomial $f$ in two variables and line in $\mathbb R^2$: http://diposit.ub.edu/dspace/bitstream/2445/159040/2/159040.pdf (**Page 16**, **Lemma**: 2.2.6) which is well understood. But I am stuck on how to solve the case with $3$ variables. Any hint or help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Note: This result does not depend on the field $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The points on a line can be written as $$\ell=\{\mathbf v_1+t\mathbf v_2\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$$ where $\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2$ are fixed vectors it $\mathbb R^3.$

$f$ might have $3$ variables, but how many variables does $f(\mathbf v_1+t\mathbf v_2)$ have?

This fact is true for $n$-variable polynomials, too.

Comment: Perhaps it might be worthwhile to also ask about the degree of $f(v_1+tv_2)$ after figuring out its variable count.